# Installed Components Not Appearing

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

iOS Unified listing of components does not list all of my installed components. It only lists Xamarin.Mobile. However, all of my other components (such as RestSharp) are Unified-API compatible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them as a nuget package instead.